# The window closes automatically as soon as it opens in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, window

I am working on a program that has one main window and several sub-windows.

When I was connecting the side windows to the action of the toolbar to show them by tapping on them, when I clicked on this action, one of them was displayed and immediately **closed**.

I did not connect the rest, but the previous one I connected works.
So far no two or more windows have been shown together.
The window worked before connecting, but this happens after connecting

My Code :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Create_List_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Create_List_Form):
        Create_List_Form.resize(350, 350)
        if Create_List_Form.close:
            print('The window was closed')

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(250, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)
        self.Action_Open_Window = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.Action_Open_Window)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.Action_Open_Window.triggered.connect(self.Open_Window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def Open_Window(self):
        Frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        My_Frame = Ui_Create_List_Form()
        My_Frame.setupUi(Frame)
        Frame.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))
        self.Action_Open_Window.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Window"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If possible, help me solve the problem.
I'm so sorry, my English is not good.

Comment: From what you're describing, you're probably using a local variable in the function connected to the signal (or even just the class in the connection), but that's just an assumption. Please understand that if you don't show us any code, we cannot just "guess" what's wrong with it. It's like calling your mechanic and telling "My car used to work, now it doesn't anymore. Can you tell me why?": nobody can fix your car if they don't see it. So, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (read that link, it's important).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help in solving the problem, I put the sample code. Help me if you can. I really cannot find the problem.

Comment: I suggest you to do some research using keywords like "pyqt window closes after opening", as there are literally hundreds of similar questions: the solution is to create a reference to the new window, otherwise it gets out of scope and gets deleted immediately. I also suggest you to *never* edit files generated with pyuic, as it's considered bad practice; read more on [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). Finally, `if Create_List_Form.close:` is wrong, and it will always print that string *as soon* as the `setupUi` function is called.

Comment: The latter is because using `if someFunction:` corresponds to `if True:`. If you want to wait for a window to close before going on with the code, use a QDialog and call `exec_()` to show it, otherwise subclass the widget (QFrame, in your case), create a custom signal for it, and emit that signal in the override the `closeEvent()`.